# How can I get mode(s) of pandas dataframe object values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, counter

I have a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) containing numerous columns. I am interested in just one of those columns ('names') whose type = 'object'. I want to answer three questions about this column:

1. What value(s) appear most often excluding nan values?
2. How many values meet that criteria (count of value in answer #1)?
3. How often do those values appear?

I started with a large dataframe (df). The column I am interested in is called 'names'. First, I used collection.Counter to get the number of occurrences for each unique value in the 'names' column:

```
In [52]: cntr = collections.Counter([r for i, r in df['names'].dropna().iteritems()])
Out[52]: Counter({'Erk': 118,
    'James': 120,
    'John': 126,
    'Michael': 129,
    'Phil': 117,
    'Ryan': 126})
```

Then I converted the Counter back to a dataframe:

```
In [53]: df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cntr, orient='index').reset_index()
In [54]: df1 = df1.rename(columns={'index':'names', 0:'cnt'})
```

This gave me a pandas dataframe containing:

```
In [55]: print (type(df1), df1)
Out[55]: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
       names    cnt
    0      Erk  118
    1    James  120
    2     Phil  117
    3     John  126
    4  Michael  122
    5     Ryan  126
```

The next part is where I need a bit of help. My desired output in this example is:

Answer #1 = [John, Ryan]

Answer #2 = 2

Answer #3 = 126

I am not convinced using the Counter was the best option, so I am open to options that stay within the dataframe without bouncing between dataframe to counter back to dataframe.

Comment: You can take a look at the value_counts() method which will be very helpful here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html.
In your case df1 = df['names'].value_counts()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get that information directly from the `Counter` like:

#### Code:

```
from collections import Counter

data = Counter({'Erk': 118, 'James': 120, 'John': 126,
                'Michael': 122, 'Phil': 117, 'Ryan': 126})

by_count = {}
for k, v in data.items():
     by_count.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
max_value = max(by_count.keys())
print(by_count[max_value], len(by_count[max_value]), max_value)
```

#### Results:

```
['John', 'Ryan'] 2 126
```

Comment: Preciously what I needed. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

There is a helper method that does just what you want : [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). It is efficient even for large dataframes.

```
df1 = df['names'].value_counts()
# question 3
q3 = df1.max()
# question 1
q1 = df1.loc[df1 == q3].index.tolist()
# question 2
q2 = len(q1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention mode

```
from scipy import stats
Val,cnt=stats.mode(df1.cnt)
Val
Out[349]: array([126], dtype=int64)
cnt
Out[350]: array([2])

df1.names[df1.cnt.isin(Val)].tolist()
Out[358]: ['John', 'Ryan']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pandas built in mode i.e

```
m = df1['cnt'].mode()
0    126
dtype: int64

sum(df1['cnt'].isin(m))
2

df1[df1['cnt'].isin(m)]['names']

3    Ryan
4    John
Name: names, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but I have done this - you'll need to import the statistics module in python along with pandas.

```
data_cut = data.groupby(['HIGH_LEVEL_CATEGORY','SKU']).agg({'M2': ['mean','median', 'min', 'max', 'count', 'var', 'std', 'sum', stats.mode]
                                           }).sort_index().reset_index()

data_cut.columns = ['HIGH_LEVEL_CATEGORY'
                    ,'SKU'
                    , 'M2_Mean'
                    ,'M2_Median'
                    , 'M2_Min'
                    , 'M2_Max'
                    , 'M2_Count'
                    , 'M2_Var'
                    , 'M2_Std'
                    , 'M2_Sum'
                    , 'M2_Mode'
                    ]
```